# Area and dimensions of ee.Geometry.Rectangle

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am using Google Earth Engine to analyze small areas and defining an square around each point. I need some help understanding how to get the correct measurements. I wanted to know if there is way to

- Make a rectangle or square passing specific dimensions in meters. In the code below, 1E-4 is not the same as 21 m.
- From a rectangle, calculate width and length in meters. I used Rectangle.Perimeter and Rectangle.Area which give me the correct results but Rectangle.Length returns zero. I also thought of looking at the coordinates of the rectangle to calculate the width and length but the coordinates seem to be the same (shown in figure below)

Here is my code. I know GEE returns values in meters which are very close to what I expect to see.

```
var makeRectangle = function(point, xDistance, yDistance, proj){
  var geometry = 
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle(
      [point[0] - xDistance, 
       point[1] - yDistance,
       point[0] + xDistance, 
       point[1] + yDistance], proj, false);
  return geometry
}

var p = [-80.2081553905,25.8888877858]
var xDistance = 1E-4
var yDistance = 1E-4
var rect = makeRectangle(p, xDistance, yDistance,'EPSG:4326')
Map.addLayer(rect)
print(rect.area(1E-3))
print(rect.perimeter(1E-3))
print(rect.length())
print(rect.coordinates())

Map.setCenter(p[0], p[1], 21);
Map.setOptions('satellite');
Map.addLayer(ee.Geometry.Point(p), {color: '#FFFF00'});
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area and distance are best done in a projected coordinate reference system where the unit is meters instead of the degrees angle units of the default `'EPSG:4326'` projection.

You can define a similar function that generates a rectangle from a center point and x and y extensions, just do it in a projected CRS. The example below takes lat and lon as the center point and x and y extension arguments as meters. The lat-lon point is transformed to the projected CRS (units are now meters) and then the x and y extensions are applied to construct the rectangle. You'll notice that the precision is not perfect (can't set error margin lower than 0.001) and the rectangle is reprojected to 'EPSG:4326' when displayed on the map, so may appear rotated a bit depending on how far the rectangle is from the CRS origin (but remains true to the projected CRS dimensions and position).

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/800daf4527b91fd8126a60407ad86b24)

```js
// Define a function that will make a rectangle from a center point
// based on x and y extension distance and projection parameters.
function makeRectangle(point, xRadius, yRadius, proj) {
  var pointLatLon = ee.Geometry.Point(point);
  var pointMeters = pointLatLon.transform(proj, 0.001);
  var coords = pointMeters.coordinates();
  var minX = ee.Number(coords.get(0)).subtract(xRadius);
  var minY = ee.Number(coords.get(1)).subtract(yRadius);
  var maxX = ee.Number(coords.get(0)).add(xRadius);
  var maxY = ee.Number(coords.get(1)).add(yRadius);
  var rect = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([minX, minY, maxX, maxY], proj, false);
  return rect;
}

// Define inputs for making a rectangle from center point.
var point = [-122.0522, 37.00704];  // lat, lon
var xRadius = 50; // meters
var yRadius = 50; // meters
var proj = 'EPSG:3310'; // California Albers Equal Area projection

// Make a rectangle from center point.
var rect = makeRectangle(point, xRadius, yRadius, proj);

// Show the retangle and point.
Map.setOptions('SATELLITE');
Map.centerObject(rect, 17);
Map.addLayer(rect, {color: 'blue'}, 'Rectangle');
Map.addLayer(ee.Geometry.Point(point), {color: 'yellow'}, 'Point');

// Print some info about the rectangle.
print(rect.area(0.001)); // Should be 10,000
print(rect.perimeter(0.001)); // Should be 400
print(rect.length());
print(rect.coordinates());
```

Note that `.length()` is only used to calculate the length of line geometries, of which this rectangle geometry has none, hence the 0 length.

Comment: I ran the code and yes, the rectangle is rotated. Any way to work around this? Will this affect Export operations?

Comment: update, found projected CRS system for florida. In case anyone needs a different system I found this link https://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=albers+equal

Comment: Glad you found a CRS that works well for your region. Regarding export... as long as you set the `crs` parameter in the export function to the same as `transform` function, it will maintain the position and dimensions. Additionally, when viewing it in a GIS, set the GIS canvas to the same CRS.

Comment: I tried doing this in python however, the folium library does not display the rectangles correctly. The projected coordinates are the same as the ones obtained in google earth engine editor but when trying to display I get the message "Could not display polygon". Is there a way to obtain the coordinates back into the 'EPSG:4326' projection?

Comment: how could it be possible to do it such as the input EPSG should't be change each time a rectangle in a new location is drawn, for instance either it is in California or in Florida or other in France... ?